# Updating text field when change the value of a select field

Tags: php, jquery, html

In this test I have a simple form with two fields. I need upadate the text field when a user select an option in the select field.

This is the html code:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <input type="text" name="dst" id="dst" value="" />
  <select name="contactos" id="contactos">
    <option value="-1">No selected</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

This is the jquery code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#contactos").change(function(event){
   var id = $("#contactos").find(':selected').val();
     $.getJSON('contacback.php?contactoID='+id, function(data) {
         $.each(data, function(i,item) {
           if (item.field == "dst") {
              $("#dst").val(item.value); }
           });
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

(added)This is the php code:

```
<?php require_once('Connections/cnx3.php'); ?>
<?php

$colname_rsContactos = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['contactoID'])) {
$colname_rsContactos = $_GET['contactoID'];
}

mysql_select_db($database_cnx3, $cnx3);
$query_rsContactos = sprintf("SELECT contactoID, telefono FROM contactos WHERE contactoID = %s",
GetSQLValueString($colname_rsContactos, "int"));
$rsContactos = mysql_query($query_rsContactos, $cnx3) or die(mysql_error());

while ($fila = mysql_fetch_array($rsContactos)) {

$json = array('field' => 'dst',
              'value' => $fila['telefono']);
}

echo json_encode($json);

mysql_free_result($rsContactos);
?>
```

The query to php is sent OK and the JSON answer it's also OK
[image of JSON reply](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10101053/json1.jpg)

But the value of #dst is not updated. Any helps is welcome !!

Comment: Sorry to do this to you, but could we also see a bit of the JSON that's getting returned? Also, do you actually intend the each in the jQuery? If you're only looking for a specific field, you could just dig in the JSON yourself rather than iterate over it.

Comment: do you have JQ initialized as a jQuery object? as far as I can tell, jQuery or $ is used by default to access jQuery, not JQ...

Comment: @attack: +1
AS you are getting only one record each is not needed, and If you are confused because you are using WHILE in the back-end then don't forget that $json variable is getting override (in case the iteration is actually happening :)

Comment: And by the way, to find the 'selected' option use this:
var id = this.value;

Comment: I have added an image of JSON reply. I'm working on two examples. In the second example I need to update two text fields, so I used the function each. Thanks for showing me the problem, now it's solved. Just: if(data.field == "dst") {

Comment: ...Sorry I've pressed enter. $("#dst").val(data.value); } });

Answer (score 0):

(Answered in a question edit and comments. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> Solved!! Thanks to @Attack the `jQuery` script:

```
$("#contactos").change(function(event){
    var id = $("#contactos").find(':selected').val();
      $.getJSON('contacback.php?contactoID='+id, function(data) {
        if (data.field == "dst") {
            $("#dst").val(data.value);
            }
      });
 });
```